# ThinkingSphinx Error: such filter attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to integrate **ThinkingSphinx** into my project using the [doc](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/). For a `User` **model** with **attributes** `first_name` and `last_name` I have created the indexes as:

User.rb

```
define_index do
  indexes :first_name
  indexes :last_name
end
```

Then I run the commands:

```
rake ts:index
rake ts:start
```

This starts my search. I get the results when I use the following command to search:

```
User.search('swati')
```

But When I run

```
User.search :with => {:first_name => "swati"}
```

It gives me the error:

```
Sphinx  Sphinx Daemon returned error: index user_core: no such filter attribute 'first_name'
Sphinx  Caught Sphinx exception: index user_core: no such filter attribute 'first_name' (0 tries left)
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index user_core: no such filter attribute 'first_name'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.13/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:438:in `block in populate'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.13/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:606:in `call'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.13/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:606:in `retry_on_stale_index'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.13/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:426:in `populate'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thinking-sphinx-2.0.13/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:187:in `method_missing'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/swati/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I searched for a possible solution on stackoverflow and it has been asked to run the commands `rake ts:index` and `rake ts:rebuild`. I have run this commands but it didn't help me.

Please help me figure out a solution for this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create an attribute with **has** in the index, **rebuild**, and then use **with**

```
has :first_name
```

**Has** creates an attribute, and **with** is used as a filter (for attributes) http://pat.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#filters

Also check http://pat.github.com/ts/en/indexing.html#attributes for filters.

Answer (score 4):

Be carefull, `rake ts:reindex` and `rake ts:rebuild` are different.

If you add a new index, you need to rebuild.

If you are paranoiac like me, try everything:

```
rake ts:rebuild
rake ts:reindex
rake ts:restart
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure your index is [defined properly](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/indexing.html).